# Azure Service bus Queue using C# : BadImageFormatException when calling QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString

Tags: c#, macos, azure-webjobs

I am using VS2017 in Mac( with latest packages added for Azure Service Bus), to pull a message from Service bus Queue in Azure. On execution of below code, getting the error

> BadImageFormatException - could not resolve field token 0x0400089c

Its coming from CreateFromConnectionString and the stack points to MessageFactory.create call which happens under the hood, on our call to CreateFromConnectionString.

Got many pointers like x86 issue and all, but none were certain on what to look into. I was using Release x86, then tried Rel AnyCpu as well.

Does anyone faced this issue before or any pointers to resolve this.

```
string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://spxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=Root**Key;SharedAccessKey=xxxx.......xxxxxxxx=";
        string queueName = "spqueue";
        QueueClient client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
```

Also did an trail by creating the MessageFactory in the program itself. Got same error at MessagingFactory.Create

Also connectionString and queue name are fine, as I am able to generate the Authorization token correctly using this code and postman connected to the Q using the same without any issues.

Thanks!
Let me know if any additional details needs to be added.

Comment: What is the version of Microsoft Azure Service Bus package you referenced?

Comment: Hi, I tried using both 'Microsoft Azure Service Bus'  version 4.1.3 and then with 'Microsoft Azure Webjobs Service Bus' version 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Visual Studio 2017 for Mac provides the ability for using Xamarin and .NET Core to build mobile,web, and cloud applications on macOS. Per my understanding,
 the [Microsoft Azure Service Bus 4.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus) targets on the traditional .NET Framework, you could try to use the next generation Azure Service Bus .NET Standard client library [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 0.0.7-preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/0.0.7-preview).

Comment: Thanks Bruce. Will try it out and let you know.